# How to save enum class in a HashMap?

Tags: java, dictionary, enums, hashmap

Let us say we have following enums:

```
public enum AnimalImages {
TIGER,BEAR,WOLF;
}

public enum CarImages {
BMW,VW,AUDI;
}
```

Now I want to save these enum classes in a HashMap:

```
Map<String,Enum<?>> enumMap=new HashMap<String,Enum<?>>();
enumMap.put("AnimalImages",???????);
```

What I should enter instead of the question marks?

Comment: You want to store all values of a given `enum` behind a single key, or what would you want to do?

Comment: An enum? ...... What's the ultimate purpose? Is this something that should be handled by the enums themselves?

Comment: Mich Mnemonic : this is exactly what I want!

Comment: @HakanKiyar do you want to store in enum map all your enum as keys and their values as values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To explicitly answer to your question, you have to put the enum value as this:

```
Map<String,Enum<?>> enumMap=new HashMap<String,Enum<?>>();
enumMap.put("AnimalImages", AnimalImages.TIGER);
```

However, if you want to put all the value belonging to an enum, then you could leverage `values()` method and also change your map to `Map<String,Enum<?>[]>` so you can use this:

```
Map<String,Enum<?>[]> enumMap=new HashMap<String,Enum<?>[]>();  // Note Enum<?>[] array
enumMap.put("AnimalImages", AnimalImages.values());
enumMap.put("CarImages", CarImages.values());
```

---

Another approach, with a shorten signature can be something like this:

```
Map<String, Object> enumMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
enumMap.put("AnimalImages", AnimalImages.values());
enumMap.put("CarImages", CarImages.values());
```

Another way that **[bali182](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126273/bali182)** pointed in this comment, you could use:

```
Map<String, Collection<? extends Enum<?>>> enumMap = new HashMap<>();
enumMap.put("AnimalImages", Arrays.asList(AnimalImages.values()));
enumMap.put("CarImages", Arrays.asList(AnimalImages.values()));
```

Comment: Why not use `Map<String, Collection<? extends Enum<?>>>` and `#put("AnimalImages", Arrays.asList(AnimalImages.values()))`? This way we know a little bit more about the types?

Comment: @bali182 yes, it's valid too. Updated now.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question:

```
enumMap.put("AnimalImages", AnimalImages.WOLF);
enumMap.put("Cars", CarImages.AUDI);
```

But you can also do

```
Map<String, AnimalImages> enumMap = new HashMap<String, AnimalImages>();
```

And this way `enumMap.get("AnimalImages")`, and this way you won't have to type check and cast it.

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is to create a `Map` that contains all values of a given `enum`, I would use a mapping of `String` keys into [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) values:

```
Map<String, EnumSet<?>> enumMap = new HashMap<String, EnumSet<?>>();
enumMap.put("AnimalImages", EnumSet.allOf(AnimalImages.class));
enumMap.put("CarImages", EnumSet.allOf(CarImages.class));

for (Map.Entry<String, EnumSet<?>> e : enumMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(String.format("key: [%s], values: %s", 
        e.getKey(), e.getValue().toString()));
}
```

`EnumSet` is a specialized `Set` implementation, which is represented internally as a bit vector. Its sole purpose is to provide an efficient and easy way to store `enum`s.